# getter in type script not working !!! it always throwgh the error or return undefined

Tags: typescript

```
class Department {
    protected employees: string[] = [];

    constructor(private readonly id: string, public name: string) {
    }

    describe(this: Department) {
        console.log(`Department (${this.id}): ${this.name}`);
    }


    }
}
```

I craeted a class then extends it with another

```
class AccountingDepartment extends Department{
    private readonly lastReport: string;

    get mostRecentReport() {
        if (this.lastReport) {
            return this.lastReport;
        }
        throw new Error('no report found.');
    }

    set mostRecentReport(value: string) {
        if (!value) {
            throw new Error('enter valid value')
        }
        this.addReport(value);
    }

    constructor(id: string, private reports: string[]) {
        super(id, 'Accounting');
        this.lastReport = reports[0];
    }



    addReport(text: string) {
        this.reports.push(text);
    }

    PrintReport() {
        console.log(this.reports);
    }
}
```

to use getter and setter as above

```
const Accounting = new AccountingDepartment('D2', []);

Accounting.addReport('every thing is ok...');
Accounting.mostRecentReport = 'welecome';
Accounting.PrintReport();
console.log(Accounting.mostRecentReport);
```

what i`m doning wrong
my code return the error (throw new Error('no report found.');) after adding it, !!
if i comment the error it returns undefined !!

Comment: Try removing `readonly` for `lastReport` and in constructor of `AccountingDepartment` add empty array check `this.lastReport = reports[0]; //empty array`

Comment: I tried both ,, if i use empty array i got error on compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never assign `lastReport` value after it is initialized in the constructor
Update the addReport method as follows

```
    ...
    private lastReport: string;
    ...
    addReport(text: string) {
        this.reports.push(text);
        this.lastReport = text;
    }
    ...
```